# NUL Character is getting written to start and end of a file in CSV

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nul

I am trying to write some contents of text file to a csv file using spark databricks write package.
However, i am getting NUL character getting added to start and end of each line
Output : NUL"Transactions","Exit","Core1.0","Trade"2018-12-10T10:47:42Z"NUL

Expected output :"Transactions","Exit","Core1.0","Trade"2018-12-10T10:47:42Z"

code below :

```
df.write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("header","false")
  .option("delimiter",",")
  .option("quote","\u00000")
  .csv(path)
```

Comment: Try adding these opations .option("quote", "\"").option("escape", "\"")

Comment: @ApurbaPandey, Thanks, However i am now facing the below error.java.lang.RuntimeException: escape cannot be more than one character